# elasticsearch and filters optimization

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Does elasticsearch optimize filters automatically? For example: In an "and" filter, if there are multiple numeric range filters defined separately for gte and lte operators instead of one range filter with both lte and gte bounds, will it cause any performance issues? Would ES automatically optimize these filters?

```
"filter" : {
"and" : [
    {
    "range" : {
            "age" : {
            "gte": 10
            }
    }
    },
    {
    "range" : {
            "age" : {
                "lte": 90
            }
    }
    },
    {
    "range" : {
            "age" : {
            "gte": 30
            }
    }
    }                                                               
]}
```

**Update**

Wanted to add: while it makes sense to combine the bounds, I wanted to check this incase when my users who can dynamically create filters do such a scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main rule of thumb with filters is that you should always apply the most restrictive filters first, so as to reduce the set of matched documents and allow the next filter to work on as few documents as possible.

Moreover, in the case you're showing, it doesn't really make sense to have three different `range` filters for the same `age` field, you should consolidate them into a single one:

```
"filter": {
    "range": {
        "age": {
            "gte": 30,
            "lte": 90
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that you should prefer `bool/must` over `and` filters whenever possible as explained [in this excellent article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets), mainly because `and` filters are not cached.

Finally, the above only applies to pre-2.0 Elasticsearch version. As of 2.0, the whole query/filter DSL will be [completely overhauled](https://www.elastic.co/blog/better-query-execution-coming-elasticsearch-2-0) and queries will be much smarter.

**UPDATE**

Since your users can create their own filters, the main rule of thumb stays, i.e. you should try to order the filters in such a way that the most restrictive filter comes first. However, if your users really have the power to create their own filters and you're not interfering with what they submit, then you should educate them (if at all possible) on how to best create filters.